# Average on group totals i Reporting Services 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to make an average on group totals in SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 with a tablix.

Seems to be the same problem that this question is struggeling with...however there are no responses: [SQL 2005 Reporting Services - Wrong Average Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936075/sql-2005-reporting-services-wrong-average-values)

My tablix looks like the following:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       |         | Product A | Product B |
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       | Average |       ??? | ???       |
|       |         |           |           |
| Week1 |         |       550 | 175       |
|       | Day 1   |       250 | 100       |
|       | Day 2   |       200 | 50        |
|       | Day 3   |       100 | 25        |
|       |         |           |           |
| Week2 |         |       600 | 240       |
|       | Day 1   |       300 | 200       |
|       | Day 2   |           | 30        |
|       | Day 3   |           | 10        |
+-------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

The average should only be calculated for the week-totals. I.e. for Product A the average should be (550+600)/2=575.

My formula for average looks like the following:

```
=Avg(Fields!WeekTotal.Value)
```

however this gives a wrong result - my guess is that it takes the days into account aswell?

The question gets harder, because sometimes i do not have the Days sale, in which case the WeekTotal will be a prediction

My dataset, which comes from a SQL Server table, contains the following data:

```
+---------+------+-----+-----------+----------+
| Product | Week | Day | WeekTotal | DayTotal |
+---------+------+-----+-----------+----------+
| A       | 1    | 1   | 550       | 250      |
| A       | 1    | 2   | 550       | 200      |
| A       | 1    | 3   | 550       | 100      |
| B       | 1    | 1   | 175       | 100      |
| B       | 1    | 2   | 175       | 50       |
| B       | 1    | 3   | 175       | 25       |
| A       | 2    | 1   | 600       | 300      |
| A       | 2    | 2   | 600       | NULL     |
| A       | 2    | 3   | 600       | NULL     |
| …       | …    | …   | …         | …        |
+---------+------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply sum all the detail values (at day level) then divide by the number of unique weeks. Something like this...

```
=Sum(Fields!DayTotal.Value)/CountDistinct(Fields!Week.Value)
```

In your sample `CountDistinct(Fields!Week.Value)` will return `2`

This all assumes you have a simple Matrix as your report design something like this...

[image]

The expression is the expression above to calculate the average.

Please note in my sample data I have more detail so I grouped by day as well as week. In your case you don;t need to group by day (but it will still work if you do)

*Also, you don't need the week total as you can simply sum the day totals at the week group level.*

**UPDATE based on OP comments:**

As you need to use the actual week totals in your data (which are not always just a sum of the day totals as I thought previously) we will have to edit the dataset and do a bit of the work there.
Below is the code is used to generate your sample dataset.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Product varchar(1), [Week] int, [Day] int, WeekTotal int, DayTotal[int]) 
INSERT INTO @t                                                                                                 
VALUES        
('A', 1, 1, 550, 250), 
('A', 1, 2, 550, 200), 
('A', 1, 3, 550, 100), 
('B', 1, 1, 175, 100), 
('B', 1, 2, 175, 50), 
('B', 1, 3, 175, 25), 
('A', 2, 1, 600, 300),
('A', 2, 2, 600, NULL), 
('A', 2, 3, 600, NULL)

SELECT 
    *
    , CAST(WeekTotal as float) / COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Product, [Week]) as WeekTotalAverage
 FROM @t
```

Notice that I now return an extra column `WeekTotalAverage` (I know, poor name!). What this does is give us an average per product/week of the weektotal, we can then simply replace the daytotal in the previous expression with this field. The dataset output looks like this.

```
Product Week    Day WeekTotal   DayTotal    WeekTotalAverage
A       1       1   550         250         183.333333333333
A       1       2   550         200         183.333333333333
A       1       3   550         100         183.333333333333
A       2       1   600         300         200
A       2       2   600         NULL        200
A       2       3   600         NULL        200
B       1       1   175         100         58.3333333333333
B       1       2   175         50          58.3333333333333
B       1       3   175         25          58.3333333333333
```

I've CAST the result of this column to a float or we end up losing fractions of the numbers when the result is recurring. So in this case product B week 1 has three entries so we take the week total (165) and divide by 3 to give us 58.33 recurring.

The report design changes a little too. It now looks like this.

[image]

The week total is now just `[WeekTotal]` (previously it was `[SUM(DayTotal)]`) and the expression for the Average is now..

```
=Sum(Fields!WeekTotalAverage.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!Week.Value)
```

In the matrix, there are two row groups, the first groups by `Week` and the second (child group) is grouped by `Day`. The column group is grouped on `Product`.

Comment: Hi Alan. Thank you for your response.. I think this is the right way to go, however i forgot to mention that sometimes i do not have a DayTotal, meaning that the WeekTotal is a Forecast. 
So if I take the SUM of DayTotal i will miss data for the weeks where there are only WeekTotals. I have updated my question to this....do you have an idea on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've updated the answer (I've left the old answer in too so scroll down)

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to create a second recordset that has only one weekly total entry for every week, and then take the average from that scope rather than the recordset used for the detailed part of the report.